# systemd units won't auto-start

Tags: 16.04, systemd

I have a server that I'd like to use to listen to Amazon SQS queues for various tasks.

Because the work is parallel, I'd like to have 10 of program "a", 20 of "b", etc.

I created a@.service, b@.service as a template, and then created a-static.service, which has Wants=a@1.service, a@2.service, etc

and a b-static.service, that has b@1.service, etc.

The problem is that when I reboot the host, the jobs don't start. However, if I run systemctl start a-static.service, the jobs *do* start. (a-static and b-static should start because they have multi-user.target)

So:
1- Why aren't the jobs starting at boot?
2- Is the way that I'm doing the unit template file, and then having the "static" call it multiple times the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

First, to handle managing a group of related services, I recommend using `target`. You can find the details at [How to create a virtual systemd service to stop/start several instances together?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283770/20239).

The benefit of using a target is that you can stop and start all the services as a group or individually.

Second, you have to *enable* services for them to start at boot. Enabling a unit runs whatever directives you have in the `[Install]` section of your unit files. You can check if a unit is enabled or not with `systemctl status your-unit` or simply `systemctl is-enabled your-unit`.